# Can you assign date to a variable in jekyll?

Tags: html, jekyll, liquid

This is what I'm currently attempting, however it does not process...

```
    {% assign current_month = {{ site.time | date: '%m' }} %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove extra brackets :

```
{% assign current_month = site.time | date: '%m' %}
```

Answer (score 0):

How did you use the variable?

{% assign current_month = {{ site.time | date: '%m' }} %}

{{ current_month }}

Will out put the current month.